# Como reemplazar array por otro array

Tags: html, array

Agradecería mucho su ayuda, soy nuevo en los arrays y de verdad les agradecería un monton.

Este es el array base que tengo que tiene como índice de 0 a 3

```
const arrayBase = [
  {
       fruit: orange
       color: red
       vehicle: ford
     },
  {
       fruit: strawberry
       color: green
       vehicle: audi
     },
  {
       fruit: banana
       color: pink
       vehicle: ford
     },
  {
       fruit: watermelon
       color: brow
       vehicle: audi
     }
]
```

Este es un array diferente pero tiene el mismo index que quiero reemplazar en el array base el cual es el indice 2

```
const arrayIndex = [  
     {
       fruit: lemon
       color: white
       vehicle: lambo
       name: Paulo
       music: rock
     }
]
```

Este es el array ya reemplazado por el indice 2

```
const arrayActualizado = [
  {
       fruit: orange
       color: red
       vehicle: ford
     },
  {
       fruit: strawberry
       color: green
       vehicle: audi
     },
  {
       fruit: lemon
       color: white
       vehicle: lambo
       name: Paulo
       music: rock
     },
  {
       fruit: watermelon
       color: brow
       vehicle: audi
     }
]
```

Esta es la forma que e estado intentando, pero no logro que tenga la forma del arrayActualizado.

```
 arrayBase.forEach((value,index) => {
   arrayBase[index].setValue(arrayIndex[index]);
 }
```

Comment: ¿Esa es la sintaxis correcta para los arrays con objetos en javascript?  Si pego eso en el jsfiddle.net me da errores por todos lados. Por favor, edita tu pregunta poniendo datos con los que podamos tratar para poder ayudarte mejor, gracias.

Comment: Todo esta mal. Debe ser: `fruit: "lemon",`. Entre comillas y al final con coma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes iterar el arrayBase e ir creando el nuevo arrayActualizado haciendo push de la información que te interesa, o puedes modificar directamente la posición del arrayBase que quieras con la nueva información.

Te dejo el código completo abajo para que lo pruebes tu mismo.
Tienes dos ejemplos:

1- Creando un array nuevo ( arrayActualizado ) y llenándolo con la información que nos interesa.

2- Modificando el arrayBase para que en la posición 2 contenga los datos de la posición 0 del arrayIndex.

Un saludo

```js
let arrayBase = [
  {
      fruit: "orange",
      color: "red",
      vehicle: "ford"
    },
  {
      fruit: "strawberry",
      color: "green",
      vehicle: "audi",
    },
  {
      fruit: "banana",
      color: "pink",
      vehicle: "ford"
    },
  {
      fruit: "watermelon",
      color: "brow",
      vehicle: "audi"
    }
]
let arrayIndex = [  
  {
    fruit: "lemon",
    color: "white",
    vehicle: "lambo",
    name: "Paulo",
    music: "rock",
  }
]

let arrayActualizado = [];

let indexToUpdate = 2;
let newIndexData = arrayIndex[0];

// Ejemplo 1
arrayBase.forEach((value,index) => {
  if(index == indexToUpdate) arrayActualizado.push(newIndexData)
  else arrayActualizado.push(value)

});

console.log("Ejemplo 1: ",arrayActualizado)

// Ejemplo 2
arrayBase[indexToUpdate] = newIndexData;

console.log("Ejemplo 2: ",arrayBase)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Albert, si me funciono, de nuevo muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Primero hay que saber que con un ForEach, no se puede mutar el estado del elemento. Solamente sirve para tomarlo y aplicar ciertos criterios.
No sé si tu objetivo es dejar tal como está el primer array (arrayBase), en ese casola respuesta de Albert te sirve (crea un arreglo nuevo y mete los elementos).

Mi respuesta lo que hace es mutar el estado de tu arrayBase, es decir, cambia.
Tan solo le asigno en el índice 2, el elemento del indice 0 del otro arreglo.

```
let arrayBase = [
{
      fruit: "orange",
      color: "red",
      vehicle: "ford"
    },
  {
      fruit: "strawberry",
      color: "green",
      vehicle: "audi",
    },
  {
      fruit: "banana",
      color: "pink",
      vehicle: "ford"
    },
  {
      fruit: "watermelon",
      color: "brow",
      vehicle: "audi"
    }
]
let arrayIndex = [  
  {
    fruit: "lemon",
    color: "white",
    vehicle: "lambo",
    name: "Paulo",
    music: "rock",
  }
]

console.log(arrayBase); //Arreglo en estado inicial
arrayBase[2]=arrayIndex[0] //Aplicamos el cambio
console.log(arrayBase); //Arreglo modificado
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Miqueas me ayudaste un montón